# php writing to json file when was last time modified

Tags: php, json, timestamp

I want to store in the file, the las time it was modified/writen(timestamp). I am not sure how to approach it. I need this for client side where i can compare with jquery current time with last time file was modified and perform some actions depending on results.

here my php code

```
<?php
$temp1 =$_POST["temp1"];
$temp2 =$_POST["temp2"];
$hum1 =$_POST["hum1"];
$myArray = array("Temperature" => $temp1, "Temperature2" => $temp2, "Humidity" => $hum1);
file_put_contents("my_data.json", json_encode($myArray));
?>
```

Comment: `file_put_contents(time().".json", json_encode($myArray));`?

Comment: the os keeps track of that, why not use that data?

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

The php function filemtime() returns the last modified time of a file.  I assume this is what you want.  There is a good example there reproduced here:

```
<?php
// outputs e.g.  somefile.txt was last modified: December 29 2002 22:16:23.

$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}
?>
```

Also see stat(filename) if you want last access of the file or last time modified.